# How do I access variables of this deeply nested JSON

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I receive a JSON in response to a request.I am able to access simple variables and print them on screen.But I am not sure how to access a deep variable and print it on screen.I want to access variables inside "Offers"class.How do I go about it ?
Here is my model class.

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
[Serializable]
public class Fields
{
}
[Serializable]
public class Queries
{
}
[Serializable]
public class FacetResults
{
    public Fields fields;
    public Queries queries;
}
[Serializable]
public class Fields2
{
}
[Serializable]
public class Facet
{
    public Fields2 fields;
    public List<object> queries;
}
[Serializable]
public class Fields3
{
}
[Serializable]
public class Filter
{
    public Fields3 fields;
    public List<object> queries;
}
[Serializable]
public class Stats
{
}
[Serializable]
public class Request
{
    public string __class__;
    public Facet facet;
    public Filter filter;
    public int limit;
    public string q;
    public string sortby;
    public int start;
    public Stats stats;
}
[Serializable]
public class Brand
{
    public string __class__;
    public string homepage_url ;
    public string name ;
    public string uid ;
}
[Serializable]
public class Manufacturer
{
    public string __class__ ;
    public string homepage_url ;
    public string name ;
    public string uid ;
}
[Serializable]
public class Prices
{
    public List<List<object>> USD ;
    public List<List<object>> GBP ;
    public List<List<object>> INR ;
    public List<List<object>> CNY ;
    public List<List<object>> EUR ;
    public List<List<object>> JPY ;
}
[Serializable]
public class Seller
{
    public string __class__;
    public string display_flag ;
    public bool has_ecommerce;
    public string homepage_url;
    public string id ;
    public string name ;
    public string uid ;
}
[Serializable]
public class Offer
{
    public string __class__ ;
    public string _naive_id ;
    public string eligible_region;
    public int? factory_lead_days;
    public int? factory_order_multiple;
    public int in_stock_quantity ;
    public bool is_authorized ;
    public bool is_realtime ;
    public string last_updated;
    public int moq ;
    public object octopart_rfq_url;
    public string on_order_eta ;
    public int? on_order_quantity ;
    public int? order_multiple ;
    public string packaging ;
    public Prices prices ;
    public string product_url ;
    public Seller seller ;
    public string sku;
}
[Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public string __class__ ;
    public Brand brand ;
    public Manufacturer manufacturer ;
    public string mpn ;
    public string octopart_url ;
    public List<Offer> offers ;
    public List<string> redirected_uids ;
    public string uid ;
}
[Serializable]
public class Result
{
    public string __class__ ;
    public Item item ;
    public string snippet ;
}
[Serializable]
public class SpecMetadata
{
}
[Serializable]
public class StatsResults
{
}
[Serializable]
public class RootOb
{
    public string __class__ ;
    public FacetResults facet_results;
    public int hits ;
    public int msec ;
    public Request request; 
    public List<Result> results; 
    public SpecMetadata spec_metadata; 
    public StatsResults stats_results;
    public string user_country ;
    public string user_currency ;
}
```

Here is the class from which I want to access.

```
   namespace OctopartApi
{
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using RestSharp;
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Net;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public  class KeywordSearch1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField mainInputField;
    public Canvas can;
    public Text parts,package,pin,dersc;
    public float x, y;
    void Start () {
        mainInputField.onEndEdit.AddListener(delegate {LockInput(mainInputField); });

    }
    void LockInput(InputField input)
    {
        ExecuteSearch (input.text);

    }
    public  void ExecuteSearch(string inp)
    {
        // -- your search query --
        string query = inp;

        string octopartUrlBase = "http://octopart.com/api/v3";
        string octopartUrlEndpoint = "parts/search";
        string apiKey = "57af648b";

        // Create the search request

        var client = new RestClient(octopartUrlBase);
        var req = new RestRequest(octopartUrlEndpoint, Method.GET)
                    .AddParameter("apikey", apiKey)
                    .AddParameter("q", query)
                    .AddParameter("start", "0")
                    .AddParameter("limit", "10");
        var resp = client.Execute(req);
        string octojson = resp.Content;
        RootOb rr = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootOb> (octojson);
        Debug.Log (rr.hits);
        printingPress (rr.results);
        parts.horizontalOverflow = HorizontalWrapMode.Wrap;
        parts.verticalOverflow = VerticalWrapMode.Overflow;
    }
    public void printingPress( List<Result> reslt)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < reslt.Count; i++) {
            parts.text = parts.text+reslt [i].item.brand.name+"\n";
        }
    }
    private const string APIKEY = "57af648b";
 }
}
```

My Json is too big to be posted here so , here is a link to it :https://octopart.com/api/docs/v3/search-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future reference, you can find this by looking where `Offer` is first declared then go down from there.

**1**.The `Offer` class is declared inside the **`Item`** class as `public List<Offer> offers;`.

**2**.The `Item` class is declared inside the **`Result`** class as `public Item item;`.

**3**.Finally, the `Result` class is declared inside the **`RootOb`** class as  public `List<Result> results;`.

After finding this, you can access `Offer` class by reversing it. Start from **#3** back to **#1**.

---

```
 RootOb rr = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootOb>(octojson);
```

**#3**.`List<Result> result = rr.results;`

**#2**. `Item item = result[0].item;`

There can be more than one `Result` since it is a `List`. You use `result.Count` to check how many `Item` before accessing them.

`Item item1 = result[0].item;`

`Item item2 = result[1].item;`

`Item item3 = result[2].item;`

**#1**.`Offer offer = item.offers[0];`

There can be more than one `Offer` since it is a `List`. You use `item.offers.Count` to check how many before accessing them.

`Offer offer1 = item.offers[0];`

`Offer offer2 = item.offers[1];`

`Offer offer3 = item.offers[2];`

---

Again, it is just this:

```
RootOb rr = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootOb>(octojson);
List<Result> result = rr.results;
Item item = result[0].item;
Offer offer = item.offers[0];
```

Finally, this is best done with a for loop:

```
RootOb rr = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootOb>(octojson);
List<Result> result = rr.results;
//Loop through the Results List
for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
{
    //Get each item
    Item item = result[i].item;
    Debug.Log("Item Index: " + i + "...  mpn: " + item.mpn);

    //Loop through the Offer List
    for (int j = 0; j < item.offers.Count; j++)
    {
        //Get each offer
        Offer offer = item.offers[j];
        Debug.Log("Offer Index: " + j + "....  quantity: " + offer.in_stock_quantity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay. I owe you :). Thanks a lot. . I will try it out now

Comment: YEs, it it `result.count`. I made a mistake in the inner loop. That should be `item.offers.Count`. See my EDIT on the last loop sample.. Added more comment to that loop code.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.